# jQuery AJAX Event is Undefined on Firefox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This code works in Webkit browsers, but not Firefox. I think I need to put "event" somewhere in a parenthesis, but not sure how and where...?

html

```
<div id="calendar_nav">
       <span class="button-prev" role="button" onclick="javascript:reloadweek();" data-semana=<?php echo $weekprev; ?>>&laquo; Previous Week</span>
       <span class="button-next" role="button" onclick="javascript:reloadweek();" data-semana=<?php echo $weeknext; ?>>Next Week &raquo;</span>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
function reloadweek(){ 
    /*console.log(event.target.dataset.semana)*/

    var uploading = jQuery('div#uploading').html('<p><img width="60px" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/images/loading.gif"/></p>');
    jQuery('#calendar').load("<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/ajaxloader.php #calendar", {
        'week': event.target.dataset.semana,
    }, function() {
        today()
    })
}
```

Comment: It depends on how `reloadweek()` is being called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "onclick" attributes should look like this:

```
   <span class="button-prev" role="button" onclick="reloadweek(event);" data-semana=<?php echo $weekprev; ?>>&laquo; Previous Week</span>
```

and then your function needs an "event" parameter:

```
function reloadweek(event){
```

There's no point in `javascript:` in "onclick" handler values.

You'd really be better off using jQuery to set up your event handlers:

```
jQuery(document).on(".button-prev, .button-next", "click", function(event) {
    var uploading = jQuery('div#uploading').html('<p><img width="60px" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/images/loading.gif"/></p>');
    jQuery('#calendar').load("<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/ajaxloader.php #calendar", {
        'week': $(this).data("semana")
    }, function() {
        today();
    });
});
```

The value of `this` in the handler will be bound (by jQuery) to the element that was clicked on. Then you really don't need `event` at all, though jQuery will make sure it's passed through.

Comment: Thanks, your first solution works. But the jQuery solution doesn't seem to work. Also, could you explain why it's better to do it a jQuery way?

Comment: @Jaeeunlee keeping JavaScript out of HTML is called "unintrusive JavaScript".  The idea is that your HTML should just be HTML. It's also a lot more flexible to set up event handlers via jQuery because the library provides some useful conveniences.

Comment: Thanks for your kind explanation. Will keep in mind.